# How to define network and port in same docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to make a docker-compose file in which i am using 2 images.

1.python:3.9.2

2.postgres:13-alpine

file structure

```
.
├── ADM
│   ├── comm
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── dataframe.csv
│   │   └── data.yaml
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   ├── data_model.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   │   ├── prediction.py
│   │   └── training.py
│   ├── logs
│   │   ├── error.log
│   │   └── info.log
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── mlruns
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── trained_models
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
```

My dockerfile code for python

```
FROM python:3.9.2 
WORKDIR /ADM

COPY ./ADM/requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ADM/comm ./comm
COPY ./ADM/data ./data
COPY ./ADM/files ./files
COPY ./ADM/logs ./logs
COPY ./ADM/trained_models ./trained_models
ADD  ./ADM/main.py .

RUN python -m nltk.downloader stopwords

EXPOSE 5432
EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose file

```
services:

  classifier_backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./ADM/:/ADM/
    command: python main.py
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
      - classifier_db

  classifier_db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:

# networks:
#   default:
#     external: true
#     name: host
```

i need to use network host. if i don't do so, the docker image do run but connection doesn't establish, therefore, i need to use network_mode host.

and if i uncomment network host in docker-compose file, it gives an error saying

> docker.errors.InvalidArgument: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
> [127118] Failed to execute script docker-compose

and if i comment those lines, my browser says

*The connection was reset*

Comment: `network_mode: host` is almost never necessary; it generally completely disables Docker's networking stack, which means you can't use [the normal mechanisms](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) to communicate between containers and that `ports:` aren't an option.  Can you fix the underlying problem that's leading you down this path?

Comment: even i don't want to use unusual ways to run my docker image. if i follow the standard procedure, the ports are exposing but the browser says, 'the cnnection was reset'.

Comment: my goal is to run the container on my machine, one way or another, and after that, on production as well (GCP)